# How to remove common fields in two tables

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

I have two tables , table 1 and table 2.

The fields of table 1 are : 
`book,pen,pencil,bag`

The fields of table 2 are : 
`car,van,book,bike,pencil`

When I run the query I want the query to ignore the duplicate or common fields and return the other field.

The output should be as follows,

```
car,van,bike,pen,bag
```

Comment: whether you have any join between these two tables?

Comment: yes please, what is the common information held in both tables that allows a join? is there one? (e.g. customer_id, product_id ...)

Comment: Are they values of a single column? or column names? In other words, what do you mean by *fields*? Presently, I'm voting to put this on hold as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT x.thing FROM
(
    SELECT thing FROM dbo.Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT thing FROM dbo.Table2
) X
GROUP BY x.thing
Having Count(*) = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e219e/3/0)</kbd>

However, this will also remove items that are duplicates in their table which might or might not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sth like this:

```
delete form X
where (car  = 
    Select distinct car
    from X 
    where x);
```

distinct--> return the differents values.

Comment: He doesn't want to delete duplicates, he want to run a query that does not return duplicates. Also, he doesn't want to get unqiue values but only values which don't have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH uniontables AS  (
  SELECT    NULL AS car,
            NULL AS van,
            book,
            NULL AS bike,
            pen,
            pencil,
            bag 
  FROM      [Table 1 ]
  UNION 
  SELECT    car,
            van,
            book,
            bike,
            NULL AS pen,
            pencil,
            NULL AS bag 
  FROM [Table 2 ] )

  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM uniontables
```

Comment: This should give you the fields and any duplicate rows would be taken out.. sorry about the formatting I'm still getting used to posting

Comment: If you want the duplicates taken out of each table then you should use  DISTINCT in each select statement within the WITH(SELECT DISTINCT NULL AS car, NULL AS van, book, NULL AS bike, pen, pencil, bag FROM [Table 1 ] UNION SELECT DISTINCT car, van, book, bike, NULL AS pen, pencil, NULL AS bag FROM [Table 2 ] )

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM uniontables

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
declare @table1 table (col1 varchar(max))
declare @table2 table (col1 varchar(max))

insert into @table1 values
('book'),('pen'),('pencil'),('bag')

insert into @table2 values ('car'),('van'),('book'),('bike'),('pencil') 

;with cte
as (
select COUNT(1) as total_item, col1 from (
select col1 from @table1
union all 
select col1 from @table2
)a group by col1
)

select  col1 from cte  where total_item = 1
```